# Ext JS : How to configure combobox as multiselect and singleselect at runtime?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I am trying to dynamically configure the comboBox as **multiselect** and **singleSelect** at runtime.
I used setMultiSelect(true) amd combo.multiSelect(true) but they did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make a call to combo.reset() when enabling multiselect ? http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185300-can-we-set-multiSelect-for-a-combobox-to-false-on-the-fly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that this functionality is missing.  Seems like functionality that could be added to the core.  Here's an extension to Ext.form.ComboBox that does what you're looking for:

```
Ext.define('My.form.MultiSelectCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    setMultiSelect: function(multiSelect) {
        var me = this;
        me.multiSelect = multiSelect;
        me.createPicker();
        me.reset();
    },
});
```

Here's an example of the MultiSelectCombo in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/r3kv2/